# need to wait between multiple click triggers

Tags: vuejs2, vue-test-utils

I noticed I needed to delay click triggers if there were more than one in order for the test to pass. I couldn't figure out what was wrong since the buttons were reacting as I wanted when clicked by hand. Then I noticed the only tests failing were the ones with multiple clicks in the setting of the test e.g.:

```
someButtonWrapper.trigger('click')
someButtonWrapper.trigger('click')
```

If i just delay the subsequent clicks, it works:

```
await wait(() => someButtonWrapper.trigger('click'), 0);
```

My problems are:

1. It's ugly
2. I can't change the tests so I need it to pass without this hack.

Would you know why multiple event don't work the same way by hand and in the test ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`trigger` returns a promise so your test may be finished before finishing the clicks. try adding awaits before every regular trigger.

```js
await someButtonWrapper.trigger('click')
await Vue.nextTick()
await someButtonWrapper.trigger('click')
```

Comment: That's what I did to make the test pass but as I said I can's persist the change in the test so i'm looking for a solution in the component implementation.

Comment: Using `await` is far better than using `wait` callbacks. As you mentioned in the question, ugliness can be removed. Also, await is not any hack, there should be an `await` if you want to do other stuff after a promise.

Comment: It doesn't solve my problem but it's right. Thanks.

Comment: you may try adding nexttick wait in between [ref link](https://v1.test-utils.vuejs.org/guides/testing-async-components.html)